# Common characters/letters of two strings to upper case in java

Tags: java, split

The aim of this program is to output/replace the common letters of a string in an uppercase letter. INPUT: computer program it should OUTPUT:cOMPuteR PROgRaM

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    Scanner x =new Scanner( System.in);
    String input="";

    System.out.print("Input two words:");
    input= x.nextLine();
        String[] array = input.split(" ");
        String stringa = array[0]; 
        String stringb = array[1];


     char[] first = stringa.toCharArray();
      char[] second = stringb.toCharArray();

      for (int i = 0, max = Math.min(first.length, second.length); i < max; i++) {
        char c = first[i];
        if (c == second[i]) 
        {
          c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
          first[i] = c;
          second[i] = c;
        }
      }

      System.out.println(new String(first));
      System.out.println(new String(second));


}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how do i replace the common characters to upper case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a char array (`char[]`) for each string. Then iterate over the chars using an position index. If the chars at the position index in each String are the same, update the char in both. And finally print the array (as `String` to get something legible).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  char[] first = args[0].toCharArray();
  char[] second = args[2].toCharArray();

  for (int i = 0, max = Math.min(first.length(), second.length()); i < max; i++) {
    char c = first[i];
    if (c == second[i]) {
      c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
      first[i] = c;
      second[i] = c;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(new String(first));
  System.out.println(new String(second));
}
```

---

After clarification of your question, here's the code that should work:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  args = new String[] {"godi","doge"};
  char[] first = args[0].toCharArray();
  char[] second = args[1].toCharArray();

  for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    char c = first[i];
    char upper = Character.toUpperCase(c);
    boolean changed = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
        if (second[j] == c) {
            second[j] = upper;
            changed = true;
        }
    }
    if (changed) {
        for (int j = 0; j < first.length; j++) {
            if (first[j] == c) {
                first[j] = upper;
            }
        }
    }
  }
  System.out.println(new String(first));
  System.out.println(new String(second));
}
```

Comment: I've incorporated your code but it outputs wrong results. (check my update)

Comment: I've tried your code but if I input "computer program" it outputs "cOMPuter PrOgraM" instead of "cOMPuteR PROgRaM"

Comment: @NicGon Sorry for that, I badly cleaned between the first and second versions. It's ok now and prints out correctly in that case

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = input.split(" ");
String stringa = array[0]; 
String stringb = array[1];

char[] a = stringa.toCharArray();

for(char c : a){
String cStr = String.valueOf(c);
int i = stringb.indexOf(cStr)
stringb[i] = cStr.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: error: array required, but String found
        stringb[i] = cStr.toUpperCase();